# How do I export oracle sql developer table schema by using pl/sql scripts?

Tags: oracle, plsql, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper

everyone knows how to export table schema by using Export Wizard,
but how can I export them by using pl/sql script?

For example,
I want to export all Table schema which begin with "SYS"(ex:SYS_ROLE, SYS_USER_ROLE, SYS_USER, etc.)
Many thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean export the DDL, or export data? Where do you want to export to? PL/SQL only runs on the database server; you can't "export" directly to a client unless you spool the character output of a script to a log file.

Comment: Normally you'd export by invoking expdp in an OS script - shell script for *nix, cmd script for Windblows.  Why do you want to do it in PL/SQL?  And why do you want to export the SYS schema?  Methinks you are taking the wrong approach to solving the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

1. `DBMS_DATAPUMP` can be used to export from PLSQL, but the output export dump file(s) will reside on a location accessible directly by the Oracle database instance.
2. The `SYS` 'tables' are mostly views. You could try the `VIEWS_AS_TABLES` option `DBMS_DATAPUMP`. Or Create tables in a another schema and then export these tables, e.g do:

`CREATE TABLE myuser.sys_users AS SELECT * FROM sys.all_users`

Then export MYUSERS schema.

3. The SQL Developer export writes the data from the data grid being viewed to a variety of formats as a local file. I do not know for sure, but SQL Developer command processing is also used by SQLCI. In SQLCI you can set the output to a number of formats  including CSV, understands the same commands as SQLCI.

See this page here:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-format-query-results-with-the-set-sqlformat-command

So although not PLSQL, you could write the queries as SQL scripts, setting the appropriate `SQLFORMAT` option, `SPOOL` to a local file and that should do it. You could try running this in SQL*Developer as well to see if it works.